# Vue Filters For Input / V-Model

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, momentjs, vuetify.js

So I am very new to ES6 SPA Javascript and Vue JS. I have mostly been using JQuery.

So I have a global filter,

```
Vue.filter('formatDate', function (value) {
  if (value) {
    return moment(String(value)).format('Do MMMM YYYY')
  }
})
```

I am also using Vuetify. I can use that filter with a data table, like so,

```
{{ props.item.DateAdded | formatDate }}
```

However, its not working for me on a `v-model`, I am guesting i doing something wrong?

```
 <v-flex xs12><v-text-field v-model="profileData.DateAdded | formatDate" label="Date Added"></v-text-field></v-flex>
```

I have also tried, `v-bind:value` as its the input value I want to format? No luck.

Please help?

Thanks,

Comment: Since Vue 2 you can't filter directly on v-model. You should take a look at : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Two-Way-Filters-replaced

Comment: Yeah I sure that section but i am not sure how to get it done with my filter...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [documentaiton](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html):

> Filters are usable in two places: mustache interpolations and v-bind
> expressions (the latter supported in 2.1.0+)

So you can use  `v-bind`. You said you tried but it doesn't work, however it works in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozguruysal/mr8cqdge/1/). I've also added `@input` event handler to have the `v-model` functionality.

So basically your text field component should be like this:

```html
<v-text-field
  :value="profileData.DateAdded | formatDate"
  label="Date Added"
  @input="value => profileData.DateAdded = value"
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Just to everyone that is getting frustrated with this code - if they are applying it inside a component - remember that inside a component the value on the `@input` is the event :)

See - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components