# Vuetify date picker doesn't save the correct date if i type it in my text field

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

Good day.

I've been using vuetify to create a form and in this form i need to select a date in which i use a date picker with a computed property to format the date. If i pick the date from the date picker calendar it works just fine however when i try typing or copy-pasting the date i get an error and it returns me whatever last date i picked on the calendar. What exactly am i doing wrong?

this is the error i get:
'Computed property "computedDateFormatted1" was assigned to but it has no setter'

Here's my date picker

```
            <v-col cols="6">
              <v-menu
              ref="menu"
              v-model="menu"
              :close-on-content-click="false"
              transition="scale-transition"
              offset-y
              max-width="290px"
              min-width="290px"
              :rules="rules"
              >
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                  <v-text-field
                  v-model="computedDateFormatted"
                  label="Emissão"
                  hint="Select date"
                  persistent-hint
                  prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
                  v-on="on"
                  ></v-text-field>
              </template>
              <v-date-picker v-model="emission" no-title @input="menu = false"></v-date-picker>
              </v-menu>
          </v-col>
```

here's my computed variables and methods:

```
computed: {
computedDateFormatted () {
  return this.formatDate(this.emission)
},
}
methods: {
formatDate (date) {
      if (!date){
        return ""
      } else {
        const [year, month, day] = date.split('-')
        return `${day}/${month}/${year}`
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Visit [this link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#date-month-pickers) and have a look at `Date pickers - formatting date `.

Answer (score 0):

try using :value on text-field

```
<v-text-field :value="date">
```

then using vue filters.. you can check the documentation how to use it here.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

and then add filter at you value. for example :value="date | formatDate"
i hope it helps.

Comment: so for what i understand i should go for something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744877/vue-filters-for-input-v-model